Problem with a diode-circuit design
I have a problem with a diode circuit design problem:

[Source: Microelectronic Circuit Analysis and Design.]
Basically a circuit where the current through the Si diode is linear if:
\begin{equation}
2V < V_{in}<10V 
\end{equation}
And:
\$i_D = 0mA\$ if \$V_{in}=2V\$,
\$i_D=10mA\$ if \$V_{in}=10V\$
My attempt:

If V1 is 2V, then the voltage drop across R1 should be 1.3V and all the current flows through R2, which are in series, so values for R1 and R2 can be taken simultaneously. But if Vin = 10V, I don't know what to do.

all the current flows through R2 ... when V1 is 2 V, if R1 drops 1.3 V, then what is the voltage across R2? ... is the current the same in both resistors?

the current is the same in both resistors only if D1 drops 0V.  D1 isn't forward-biased, but does it means that it drops 0V? or can be any value from [0,0.7)? Sorry for replying with a question.

@RichardKingston Look at the chart. There's no current until about 2 V is applied. Then it suddenly starts. You have a diode model which says 700 mV across it. How many of them would it take to stop up to around 2 V? Also, what is the slope once things start conducting, finally?

Above 2V, the voltage across the diode is constant and all the change in current goes through the diode. For a voltage change of 8V you get a known change in diode current. Does that give you a hint to one of the resistor values?

Thank you. So, if I connect three diodes in series the voltage drop will be around 2V (0.7 each) then a 800 ohm resistor in series to the last diode will make it.

@RichardKingston Very good!!!! Try it out. See this for example!

@RichardKingston You are allowed to write up your own answer in your own words here. And you can even select it as the answer! Others may decide to +1 it, as well, if your write-up is good. Have a shot at it if you like.

Write the 2 equations of your circuit. Apply your conditions. Solve for R1 and R2. Quasi something as R1 = 750 R2 = 220 ... See my answer, resistors updated.

Kind of hoped you'd write up what you worked out in comments. (Very good!) But as I already have the image prepared, I will write up your thoughts below.
Yes, as you worked out you need three diodes (each dropping \$700\:\text{mV}\$) in order to prevent current until the voltage reaches \$2.1\:\text{V}\$. After that, you have a slope of about \$800\:\Omega\$. Just as you worked out.
So the circuit would look about as you see on the left, below, with the resulting transfer curve shown on the right of it:

Now, your curve actually shows an exact \$10\:\text{mA}\$ at exactly \$10\:\text{V}\$. So, technically, the resistor should be \$\frac{10\:\text{V}\,-\,3\,\cdot\,700\:\text{mV}}{10\:\text{mA}\,-\,0\:\text{mA}}=790\:\Omega\$.
So you may want to use that value, instead.
But the result is that you demonstrated a proficiency in fully understanding how to approach your problem and then solve it. Excellent!

Solution could be something like this ... Ideal conditions.

where R1 = ~ 800 Ohm and R2 = ~ 431 Ohm ...
Simulation could say something like this ... Diode generic.

